# Network Area Storage with multiple servers

Tags: ubuntu, storage, samba, network-attached-storage

I'm looking for a way to combine the space (~ 500 - 2000 GB per Server) of about 7 servers (will become more if this works good!) to one big volume as a RAID-5 which is accessible via Samba (as there are some windows clients in our network, too.)

My current environment:
7 dell servers with disk space from 500 - 2000 GB (could be configured as RAID 1 on each server but I would prefer not to do this). These servers all have internet connections and are furthermore connected together via a internal switch on a 10.0.0.0/27 subnet.

Target:
The whole space of all of these seven ubuntu servers should be connected to one big RAID-5 filesystem which can be made accessible via Samba.

I already have found the tag word "Clustered File System" and there are several systems presented in the internet, so the question is, which one are good ones and what's the specific advantages (e.g. performance, scalability, ...)

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: There's a lot of benefits and drawbacks to this approach, and I'm not convinced that this is necessarily a good idea just yet. What are you trying to gain from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Glusterfs](http://www.gluster.org/) in Distributed mode

You could also expose each server's disks via iSCSI and then use mdadm on on one of the boxes to software RAID across them and share it by Samba.

Comment: I have just decided to use Gluster for geo-replication and I am a big fan so far.